# Find Number of Days in Current Month That Fall Between Date Range In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to come up with a function that will calculate a monthly budget from within a specified date range. I tried to use SUMIFS but I can't figure out how to isolate a specific month within the range.

Example:

We have a sheet with Google Ad campaigns, with a row for each campaign.

We are running one Google Ad campaign (A) from 2/15/20 to 5/15/20 with a total budget of $3000 from which I calculate a daily budget of $33.33.

We are running a second campaign (B) from 5/15/20 to 8/15/20, also with a budget of $3,000, from which I calculate a daily budget of $32.61.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Start_Date)),Total_Budget/(End_Date-Start_Date),"")
```

In a separate sheet, I have Budget and Spend fields for each month. For May, I need it to calculate the total budget for 5/1-5/15 of Campaign A, and 5/15-5/31 of Campaign B.

I got this far (J is the Daily_Budget, G is the Start_Date, and H is the End_Date):

```
=SUMIFS(Google!J2:J30, Google!G2:G30,"<="&DATE(2020,5,1),Google!H2:H30,">="&DATE(2020,5,31))
```

Then I was at a loss for how to extrapolate the number of days from the range, so that I could then multiply them by the Daily Budget and then add them together.

I thought of going back to the sheet that contains the campaigns and adding columns for each month with a complicated conditional, and then just using SUM(), but I feel like there has to be a more elegant solution.

**UPDATE**

Per request, here is a link to the spreadsheet with the desired results manually entered: [Click here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PwiN_kQdM8QTOgp5SfRwreXmmtd1D7o75A93Kuo6fNM/edit?usp=sharing) May & June show the campaign partial month overlaps. The result I'm ultimately going for is `=(15*Google!J2)+(16*Google!J3)`.

**UPDATE 2 (24Jun20)**

Per request, I have shared the spreadsheet so that people can make a copy and experiment with formulas: [Click here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PwiN_kQdM8QTOgp5SfRwreXmmtd1D7o75A93Kuo6fNM/edit?usp=sharing).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ty

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet with desired result?

Comment: You published it to the web, so no formulas can be seen there / the file cannot be copied in order to test it. Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet via button `Share` on the top right?

Comment: I don't have the formulas. That's what the question is. I input what the results would be, and need help crafting the formulas to get me there.

Comment: Anyway, as I said before, could you share a copy of the spreadsheet via button `Share` on the top right? That could help a lot in order to test this a find a solution.

Comment: Spreadsheet is shared and can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PwiN_kQdM8QTOgp5SfRwreXmmtd1D7o75A93Kuo6fNM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function DATEDIF() [(documentation here)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en). You can set the first parameter as the first day of the month you are trying to calculate the number of days within it, and the second as the first day from another month. Example:

```
DATEDIF(DATE(2020, 1, 1), DATE(2020, 2, 1), "D")
```

You could probably make a custom function with this as well to input only the number of each month (and year, in case of leap years on February), but I don't have much experience with that unfortunately.

Comment: How do you apply that to multiple date ranges? Or, how can you incorporate that into the SUMIFS conditional?

Comment: @TyMorton Not sure exactly what you mean by multiple date ranges, but since DATEDIF() returns an integer for the number of days with the third parameter, "D", you could easily call the function multiple times which each date range and add them together.

Comment: I'm trying to determine how many days in a given month fall within the date range of a campaign. There are multiple campaigns running simultaneously, each with their own date range. So, if there was a way to combine DATEDIF and SUMIFS, that's probably close to what I need, but I can't figure out how to make that work.